# I have a nested hash and want to get the value of one of the key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, hash, hashmap

I have a nested Hash

```
[{:page=>1, 
:lines=>[
{:y=>774.0, :text_groups=>[{:x=>18.0, :width=>421.59599999999995, :text=>"-*- Demonstration Powered by HP Exstream 04/21/2015, Version 9.0.104 32-bit -*-"}]}, 
{:y=>762.0, :text_groups=>[{:x=>504.24, :width=>53.78399999999999, :text=>"July 16, 2014"}]}, 
{:y=>699.12, :text_groups=>[{:x=>54.0, :width=>80.01709144799977, :text=>"Capital One Auto Finance"}]}, 
{:y=>690.9599999999999, :text_groups=>[{:x=>54.0, :width=>59.619068135999825, :text=>"7933 Preston Road"}]}, 
{:y=>682.8, :text_groups=>[{:x=>54.0, :width=>53.450022959999956, :text=>"Plano, TX 75024"}]},...........
```

[{:page=>2, 
:lines=>[.....

This is the hash of a PDF content.
I want to get the value of 'text' "7933 Preston Road" when given the Key Value pairs of :y=>"690.9599999999999", :x=>"54.0" and :width=>"59.619068135999825"

basically what I am trying to do here is, in a PDF which is a letter, I am trying to find out what text is present at a given Coordinate.
I can get the PDF content into a hash but could not search through it and print the text for the required coordinates.

Can some one help me with this ?

Comment: Are the coordinates fixed and always the same every time?

Comment: Floating point values that long may suffer from a small amount of jitter. How close is close enough?

Comment: Right now we are assuming coordinates are fixed

Comment: not sure about the floating point values. I guess we can say + or - one or two places. does that work ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps even uglier, and with no tolerances

```
def find_location(pdf, y, x ,width)
  pdf.each do |page_hash|
    y_lines = page_hash[:lines].select{|line_hash| line_hash[:y] == y }
    y_lines.each do |y_line|
      y_line[:text_groups].each do |text_group|
        if text_group[:x] == x && text_group[:width] == width
          return text_group[:text]
        end
      end
    end
    return nil # Could not find text at that location.
  end
end

puts find_location(pdf, 690.9599999999999, 54.0, 59.619068135999825)
```

Comment: class ClassXXX; def self.find_location(...); ... ; end; end; ClassXXX.find_location(...);

Comment: I have multiple pages, when i want text from 2nd page or 3rd page how do I do that ?

Comment: This code iterates through all pages. The page_hash variable contains a :page key. You could add a page parameter and check for it in the loop. something like `next unless page_hash[:page] == page`.

Comment: Pardon, the code iterates through each page until it finds the first result. Using next would let you skip until the page you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A little ugly, but it works. You'll want to adjust the tolerances. Assuming that `pdf` is your array of hash data.

```
y = 690.959999999
x = 54.01
width = 59.619068135999
texts = pdf.map do |page|
  page[:lines].
    select {|e| (y - e[:y]).abs < 0.1}.
    map {|e| e[:text_groups]}.
    flatten.
    select {|e| (x - e[:x]).abs < 0.1 && (width - e[:width]).abs < 0.1}.
    map {|e| e[:text]}
end

puts texts.join
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working but it is displaying the result 4 times.7933 Preston Road7933 Preston Road7933 Preston Road7933 Preston Road

Comment: it is basically giving me the text at that location from all teh 4 pages in the PDF How do I limit it to give me page by page.

Comment: That I'll leave to you. You'll just need to tweak how it loops to break it apart by page.